# HTML symbol: Search for quotation marks from a page in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, symbols

Some of my pages have different languages. When I try to search the open double quotation marks exactly `“` (U+201C), Chrome returns also `”` (U+201D) and `"` (U+0022). What I do is to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> and input `“` in the text box. I also notice search for `A` returns `Ā` and `Ă`.

You can do a search for `“` in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotation_mark to feel what I have suffered.

What is the reason for Chrome to have such a behaviour?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

User-friendliness, probably. Chrome normalizes search query and searchable page contents. Most users don't see a difference between `“` and `"`, when they want to search for `“` they type in `"`. It's also easier to type because it's included in common keyboard layouts. Similarly, with my keyboard layout I can't type `Ā`. Thanks to that feature of Chrome I can just use `A` and get the same results.

Comment: though I disagree I accept it